# Unable to add a domain (purchased from godaddy.com) to the dreamhost account

Tags: web-hosting, dns, dreamhost

My client just purchased a domain from `godaddy.com` and I'm trying to add it as a new domain on their dreamhost account.

But it is unable to be added. It simply doesn't work and doesn't even show any kind of error message. What may be the issue and how can I resolve this?

Comment: I believe due to recent events you should probably change the question to "How do I transfer my domain away from godaddy"

Comment: DH has excellent customer support. This would be a perfect situation for taking advantage of it.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I'll trying contacting the support.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, contact DH and see what they have to say. But since the events of everyone pulling their domain from GoDaddy, they have been really finicky about how much freedom you have over the domain. Check out this article on it: http://mashable.com/2011/12/29/how-to-move-your-domain-name-account/#403994-Get-Your-Authorization-Code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to contact GoDaddy. How many domain can you host with them? If they only permit you to host 1 domain, of course you cant add another domain. Please kindly check it with your provider. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer your domain from godaddy to Dreamhost
Use this wiki page for transferring the domain
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transfer_your_domain_registration_to_us

or if you want to host in dreamhost not to transfer the domain
edit NS records of your domain in the DNS Setup in godaddy...

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to use Dreamhost as your registrar to be able to use Dreamhost.  I typically register my domains and GoDaddy and dream host handles mail or hosting for several of them.  To add a domain that has been registered at Godaddy to your DreamHost account:

- Start at the domain manager dreamhost panel: https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=domain.manage
- Click "Add new domain"
- Fill in the options you want
- Click the "Fully host this domain" button

If this doesn't work for you, then it is a problem at DreamHost.  You would need to contact them through their support page: https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=domain.manage